# Why do we need transpose graph (reverse edges) in GNN?

Tags: graph-neural-network

Especially in heterogeneous graphs, when we go on GNN tasks, reverse edges (transpose graph) are added and I do not know the reason exactly. Can someone explain this in a detailed way?

Comment: can you elaborate more?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it. We do it because we have to consider all possible node embeddings update to get right answers. Updating nodes that are in the interest of my task would not correctly update the nodes unless all nodes that are involved in the graph are correctly updated.

Comment: The question is so sparse that it's hard to understand; likewise, this answer is rather obscure. Can you [edit] both your question and answer to explain what problem you're trying to solve, and how this answer solves that problem?